# Matrices of boost intervals

Tags: c++, matrix, boost, intervals

I am trying to write a "divide and conquer" root estimating algorithm for a R^n->R^m function using interval arithmetics. I did this in python before, but the performance was too slow so I decided to give C++ a go, I am a total beginner.

I searched for a while to find Boosts interval library which seems convenient in dealing with my problem. However, I am required to do calculations with matrices of such intervals. Because I need to later on use matrices of interval midpoints and (pseudo-) invert them, I figured that `Eigen` might be a good way to represent my matrices.

My question: Is this approach really a good idea, especially regarding performance? And if so, how would I go on to make it possible for such a matrix to contain intervals as entry and work with the basic operations (matrix multiplication etc.)

An example of what I want to be able to do:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  VectorXd v(2);
  Interval i1(0.0, 1.0);
  Interval i2(1.0, 2.0);
  Interval i3(0.0, 0.0);
  m(0,0) = i1;
  m(1,0) = i3;
  m(0,1) = i3;
  m(1,1) = i1;

  v(0) = i1;
  v(1) = i2;

  std::cout << m*v << std::endl;
}
```

The specifications I made for the interval type are

```
 typedef boost::numeric::interval<double, boost::numeric::interval_lib::policies
                            <boost::numeric::interval_lib::save_state
                            <boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_transc_std<double> >,
                            boost::numeric::interval_lib::checking_base<double> > > Interval;
```

This should ultimately output something like (0.0,1.0), (0.0,2.0). Right now this raises the error "Assigning scalar to incomparible type Interval" and I don't have any idea on how to fix it, because Eigens matrix type naturally does not support intervals as entries.

> ```
> assigning to 'Scalar' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'Interval'
> (aka 'interval < double, boost::numeric::interval_lib::policies <
> boost::numeric::interval_lib::save_state <
> boost::numeric::interval_lib::rounded_transc_std < double > >,
> boost::numeric::interval_lib::checking_base<double> > >')
> ```

Any (noob-level!) references and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: C++ is a compiled language.  Are you getting an error when you compile or run the program?  If you get an error when you compile it, the compiler should tell you exactly which line.  The text it prints out is very verbose and informative; a summary usually is less useful.  Copy it all  and put it in `>` quote with 5 leading spaces.

Comment: @Yakk I attached the full error. I guess I have to somehow rewrite the matrix type to also take in intervals as scalars, but I really don't know how one would go about this

Comment: Don't use the convenience typedef MatrixXd, use the main Matrix type with the right template parameters (see the doc, the right choice is obvious). Depending on the operations you want to do, you may need to specialize some eigen traits for this (interval) number type, see the doc about custom number types.

Comment: That isn't the full error.  The full error would include among other things the line number.  It may also include a whole pile of other knock-on stuff.  The line the error occurs on is useful.  As are any other knock-on other error spam.  If you are using a gui the gui may be hiding the full error from you.

Comment: @Yakk I'm using atom and I left out the line (it's separated in the output so I kinda forgot, but in this specific code I get errors on all the m and v assignments), otherwise this is everything that is displayed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs say](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) that

```
typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXd;
```

Here's some fixes:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae501f7ce9daa05d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>

namespace bn = boost::numeric;
namespace bi = bn::interval_lib;

using Interval = bn::interval<
        double, 
        bi::policies<
            bi::save_state<bi::rounded_transc_std<double> >,
            bi::checking_base<double>
        > 
    >;

#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 2>;
using Vector = Eigen::Matrix<Interval, 2, 1>;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Matrix m;
    m << 
       Interval {0.0, 1.0},
       Interval {0.0, 0.0},
       Interval {0.0, 0.0},
       Interval {0.0, 1.0};

    Vector v;
    v << 
       Interval {0.0, 1.0},
       Interval {1.0, 2.0};

    Vector prod = (m*v).eval();

    std::cout << prod(0,0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << prod(1,0) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
[0,1]
[0,2]
```

Of course you can use `Dynamic` extents.

Comment: in principle exactly what I am looking for, but the "(m*v).eval();" line throws the error that * operand type is ambiguous between "matrix" and "vector", am I missing something? compiling with g++, c++14, boost 1.66 and eigen 3.3.4. The corresponding error is too long for the comment section :/

Comment: I can resolve it by using m.lazyProduct(v), but I don't understand what the problem is and there may be a performance price I'm paying for this, am I right?

Comment: I guess you used `Dynamic`, and/or Eigen in another version/configured differently in which case `m*v` might not result in an expression-template. See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html - Anyhoops, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a8f5655f673a07d) works for me too.

Comment: didn't use dynamic, but maybe a different version. Which version and compiler did you run this on?

Comment: gcc 7, eigen3 (3.3~beta1-2 ubuntu package libeigen3-dev), boost 1.66